# Select query getting "Request timed out"

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a document db collection containing approximately 4 million items.

I run a query of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ItemDate >= "2015-01-01" AND c.ItemDate < "2017-07-31"
```

This query would ultimately enumerate most items in the collection, but not all (as most items exist in that range). When I run the query in the azure portal I get an error like ": Request timed out"

I was under the impression that DocumentDb would return paged results, and I would ultimately use a continuation token to retrieve subsequent paged data. And this instance would just return documents as they were found.

Is there anything I can do with this query to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this one

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE (ItemDate >= "2015-01-01" AND ItemDate < "2017-07-31")
```

Comment: Well, that definitely runs, but it only returns one document, there should be millions that satisfy that query.

Comment: Well this return of 1 seems to be due to my limited RU of 400. If I increase to 10000, I get 100 items. Seems this query costs 7600 RUs, which seems excessive. Hopefully there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: And just to finish this off, it seems the where clause when comparing against a string is very expensive, when I added an additional date property and used a int to represent the date, the RU cost dropped 7000 to 55.

Comment: @Slicc Default indexing configuration does not include strings at a high enough precision to do efficient order by. Numeric values by default are always at highest precision and therefore you see significant difference in performance. I suggest that you read through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates